# subtract if the day of the week is a saturday or sunday

Tags: vb.net

if the subtracted date is a saturday or sunday then subtract more days, before adding to arraylist

when i do this, the date stays the same and doesnt subtract, i get a conversion string to double error

```
Dim aftersubtraction As Date
                    Dim fromatafter As Date
                    aftersubtraction = departuredate.AddDays(-dates1.Text)
                    fromatafter = aftersubtraction.AddDays(-gracep.Text)

                    If fromatafter.DayOfWeek = "Saturday" Then
                        fromatafter.AddDays(-1)
                        dates.Add(fromatafter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    ElseIf fromatafter.DayOfWeek = "Sunday" Then
                        fromatafter.AddDays(-2)
                        dates.Add(fromatafter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    Else
                        dates.Add(fromatafter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    End If
```

Comment: that's not actually a question...

Comment: well my question is how to check if a date falls on a saturday or sunday and if it does subtract a day or two and then add it to an arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
While fromatafter.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse fromatafter.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday
    fromatafter = fromatafter.AddDays(-1)
End While
dates.Add(fromatafter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

You have to assigne the date returned from AddDays to your variable.

And please set option [strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). [Why](http://weblogs.asp.net/prieck/archive/2003/10/21/32869.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken the vb dayofweek function returns an integer and not a string.

' 0 = Sunday
' 1 = Monday
' 2 = Tuesday
' 3 = Wednesday
' 4 = Thursday
' 5 = Friday
' 6 = Saturday

hence the error message.

your getting the string to double error on the

line with the if statement... becase .dayofweek does not return a string... it returns an integer... so an integer is never going to be = "Saturday" or "Sunday"... its going to be equal to 0 or 1

Comment: it works, but it wont subtract if the day is a sunday or saturday. even when i used if fromatafter.DayOfWeek.sunday

Comment: try: If fromatafter.DayOfWeek = 6 Then

Comment: thats what im using now : / i used both same result